# How can I use the Google Sign In button with the gsi CodeClient (Authorization code flow)?

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

The google sign in button doesn't render unless I use the `google.accounts.id.initialize()` method. However to use the authorization code flow I need to use create and use a CodeClient by calling `google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient()` and then manually call a `.prompt()` method on this client object.

So I can't see how I am meant to have the user click on the sign in button and then start an authorization code flow without having the user have to deal with two separate popup windows. The first to authenticate themselves and the second to authorize the back end service.

Additional context:

- This is a single page application
- I am using my own back end service
- Google sign in is the only authentication option available

Comment: Have you considered implementing the [Google One Tap sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/use-one-tap-js-api) in your app? @JJPell

Comment: You can set consent as empty string and run google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient() on callback